# Как в PHP просканировать папку и все подпапки и взять файлы с расширением html?

Tags: php, backend

Мне нужно просканировать изначальную папку и все её подпапки и подпапки подпапок и брать файлы только с расширением html.
Этот мой скрипт сканирует только самую верхнюю папку, а подпапки - нет.

```
<?php 

header('Content-Type: application/json');
$filelist = glob("../*.html");

echo json_encode($filelist);
```

Comment: $dir = 'C:/123';
$files1 = myscandir($dir);
$files1=array_values($files1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для данной задачи вам необходимо обойти все директории/поддиректории. Можете воспользоваться [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) (PHP >= 5.6)

Как пример для обхода:

```
$Dr = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('path_project/');
$List = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($Dr);
$Files = new RegexIterator($List, '/^.+\.html$/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
print_r($Files);
```

Answer (score 1):

В нормальном окружении можно написать

```
$filelist = shell_exec('find .. -name "*.php"')
```

Comment: Это где написать надо?

Comment: Там же, где и всё остальное